# When I do a group by with Entity Framework whats the name property of the list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Im trying to fill a DropDownList with a group by sentence.

Thats my sentence

```
var municipios = from p in context.Nalojamientoes 
                 group p by p.Nows_Municipio 
                 into g select g;
```

There is where I fill my DropDownList:

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = municipios.ToList();
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Nows_Municipio";
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Nows_Municipio";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

I get an Error that say "Theres not a property with name 'Nows_Municipio'"

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query

```
var municipios = from p in context.Nalojamientoes 
                 group p by p.Nows_Municipio into g 
                 select g;
```

will has as a result a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`, for further documentation on this, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Simple stated you will get, when this query executed, a sequence of groups. Each group will have as a key the `Nows_Municipio` and as members all the other properties contained in the random element of `context.Nalojamientoes`.

On the other hand, the following statement:

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = municipios.ToList();
```

will force the execution, of your query and list, which will contain the groups, we mentioned above will be created. That being said, you can't expect, that in your result `Nows_Municipio` be binded to the `DropDownList1` this way.

Insted of doing the above, you should try the following:

```
var municipios = from p in context.Nalojamientoes 
                 group p by p.Nows_Municipio into g 
                 select g.Key;
```

Then you have to bind your result to your DropDownList:

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = municipios.ToList();
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

and now you will get that you wanted.

Comment: I put the "g.key" at the end and only "DropDownList1.DataSource = municipios.ToList();" and "DropDownList1.DataBind();" and works! Thank you!